# How to access deleted records in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Assume I have a tasks application.

When the user updates a task an update button is enabled and the number of updated records is displayed. I do not manage to implement this when I delete a record.

For updates this is easily done in the controller:

```
App.TasksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    changedAmount: function(){
        @filterBy('isDirty', true).get('length');
    }.property('content.@each.isDirty');
})
```

But then when I delete a record using the `deleteRecord` function I don't manage to get the amount of changed/deleted records. Example:

```
App.TasksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
.
.
    actions: {
        delete: function(task){
            task.deleteRecord()
        }
    }
});
```

**How can I access the deleted records or at least the amount of them?**

My environment:

```
Ember      : 1.3.1.1
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.6
Handlebars : 1.2.1
jQuery     : 1.10.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the property you're looking for is `isDeleted`. So you could modify that controller to be like:

```
App.TasksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    dirtyTasks:   Ember.computed.filterBy('content', 'isDirty', true),
    deletedTasks: Ember.computed.filterBy('content', 'isDeleted', true),
    changedTasks: Ember.computed.union('dirtyTasks', 'deletedTasks')
});
```

**Update**:

I see what you mean about the content being autoupdated. I tracked this one down to the recordArrayManager being used by the Ember Store. When you issue either a `find` or a `filter` on the store, what is returned is a filtered record array, and one of the filters applied to that array is that none of the records in it can be in an `isDeleted` state. You can see that in action [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/e240a1cc7b3734f3fff6aedce4c81eb41408c656/packages/ember-data/lib/system/record_array_manager.js#L59).

Off the top of my head, I can't see a solution to this that I'm particularly satisfied with. But, if you absolutely need the content in your array controller to included deletedRecords, then you would need to override the method I linked to above in a custom RecordArrayManager class, and then set that recordArrayManager in the initialize for your application's store, as [seen here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.6/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L96).

[Here's a jsbin demonstrating it](http://jsbin.com/dolu/1/)

**Note that this is a dirty hack and you really shouldn't do it.** Frankly, I think a better solution would be to, instead of deleting the record using ember data methods, come up with your own flagged `customIsDeleted` state and set the model in that state instead of outright deleting it, if you really want it to stay on the screen.

Comment: I tried something like it but it doesn't work as the record is removed from the `content` array once I run the `deleteRecord()`. Therefore the deleted records can't be accessed directly. The question is how can it be done?...

Comment: How are you setting `content` on the controller?

Comment: My data is loaded via the RESTAdaptor and `deleteRecord()` removes it automatically from the `content`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I think I tracked it down to it's root cause, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and anyway open an issue about this on ember-data.